# Font awesome <svg> size

Tags: css, font-awesome

So I want to make this circles with icons in it, and for the icons I want to use font awesome. For the circles I use a padding trick so the circles are always circles and not ellipses.

The icons get way too big and when removing `box-sizing: border-box` way too small.

I think the `padding-top: 20%;` is the cause of the problem but I don't know how to fix this.

```css
svg{
    width: 20% !important;
    padding-top: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #ec567c;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<i class="fas fa-female"></i>
<i class="fas fa-music"></i>
<i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
```

If you take away the `box-sizing: border-box;` the icons will in the circle, but they will be way to small .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an attribute you can add to the icon to make it bigger smaller than it's default. At the time of writing the Fontawesome docs are down though so I can't get it right now... that's the best way to go about it in my opinion.

EDIT:

OK so it's  data-fa-transform="shrink-6" for making smaller. I believe you can increase the size with  data-fa-transform="shrink--6"

```
Hello
<span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
    <i class="fas fa-circle" data-fa-transform="shrink--6"></i>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
</span>
World
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vk3qw09f/395/

Adding the following JS before you load the Fontawesome JS will wrap the svg in  tags. I'd suggest you do this and style the i tags rather than the svg.

```
FontAwesomeConfig = {
    autoReplaceSvg: 'nest'
};
```

Comment: I found what you mean, those classes right? `fa-10x`, `fa-sm`, `fa-7x` etc

Comment: That's the preferred option for previous versions of Fontawesome, but you are using V5's javascript / SVG version. I've edited my answer with the correct usage.

Comment: I tried it, but the padding makes the font not able to get bigger. I found the a class for fixed height tho and that works. :D

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a possible solution to this problem

Comment: I actually noticed that `fixed height` doesn't exist, only `fixed width`. I just found this and am doing that right now, but I came to a problem. The `fa-female`  is half the width of the `fa-circle` so they wont cover eachother.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vk3qw09f/395/
or
https://jsfiddle.net/vk3qw09f/396/
Does this not give the desired results?

Comment: Got it, just giving the `fa-circle` also the right `background-color` and the `fa-female` and `margin-right` of `-15%`

Comment: uhm nvm, yours is better. Somehow when I do it its different.. But I noticed that's because of  my css.

Answer (score 6):

Font Awesome is - as the name says - a font.
That means you can change the size with `font-size`.

If you think the icon is too big: lower the font size.

If you think the icon is too small: crank that font size up.

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid. `.svg-inline--fa{ font-size: 100px; }` indeed makes it bigger.
In 6 minuts I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation about [power transforms](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms) you can simply add `data-fa-transform="grow-6"` to your icon element. It should work exactly the same as the hack using `data-fa-transform="shrink--6"`.

Edit: not sure if it applies to SVG icons as well, looks like only to icon fonts. Using Angular 7.2.12 with **@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome (0.3.0)**, **@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core (1.2.17)**, **@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons (5.8.1)** and `data-fa-transform="ANYTHING"` doesn't work for me.

Solved this problem for my project using `<fa-icon style="font-size: 2rem;" [icon]="['fab', 'facebook-f']"></fa-icon>`.